# Move an image after (x) seconds

Tags: javascript, image, animation

Im trying to make an image move to a random spot on the webpage after 5 seconds so far I have this:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
var position = 0;
var timing = setInterval(timing, 5000);

image.style.position = 'relative';


image.onclick=function move(direction){
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var right = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var bottom = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  image.style.top = top + 'px';
  image.style.left = left + 'px';
  image.style.right = right + 'px';
  image.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
}
```

How do I get it to move after 5 seconds?

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create an *moveImage* function:

```
function moveImage(){
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var right = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var bottom = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  image.style.top = top + 'px';
  image.style.left = left + 'px';
  image.style.right = right + 'px';
  image.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
}
```

2. Update the onClick to use the new function:

```
image.addEventListener('click', moveImage);
```

3. Update the interval to use the new function:

```
var timing = setInterval(moveImage, 5000);
```

The whole thing:

```
var image = document.getElementById('image');
image.style.position = 'relative';

function moveImage(){
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var right = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  var bottom = Math.floor(Math.random()*75);
  image.style.top = top + 'px';
  image.style.left = left + 'px';
  image.style.right = right + 'px';
  image.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
};

image.addEventListener('click', moveImage);
var timing = setInterval(moveImage, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with this! also a quick question what is the difference if you make the image.style.position to absolute instead of relavtive?

Comment: relative: means it is moved relative to where it would normally be. Absolute will move it to  relative to the nearest parent who is already position relative::: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/